# Customize QSplitter handle color

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4

How to change the color of QSplitter handle

```
m_pSplitMainWin->setHandleWidth(10);
m_pSplitMainWin->setStyleSheet("QSplitter::handle:background-color: rgb(55, 100, 110);");
```

This is not working, PLease give your valuable input

Comment: Check this : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qsplitter

Answer (score 3):

Works for me:

```
QSplitter::handle
{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

More complex example:

```
QSplitter#editorViewSplitter::handle:horizontal
{
    border-left: 1px solid lightGray;
}

QSplitter#editorViewSplitter::handle:vertical 
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightGray;
}
```

Comment: how i will do for m_pSplitMainWin

Comment: using m_pSplitMainWin how can I do this

Comment: Try m_pSplitMainWin->setStyleSheet("QSplitter::handle {background: rgb(55, 100, 110);} "); Pay your attention on "{" instead if ":".

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
YourSplitter->setStyleSheet("QSplitter::handle{background: #444444;}");
```