# Change handle color of QSplitter

Tags: qt, qt4

I am using a `QSplitter`, but the handle color is not changing, it has always the default color:

```
m_pSplitMainWin = new QSplitter;
m_pSplitMainWin->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);

m_pSplitMainWin->setHandleWidth(10);
m_pSplitMainWin->setStyleSheet("QSplitter::handle:background-color: rgb(55, 100, 110);");
```

I got some idea from [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924036/customize-qsplitter-handle-color) but I am not able to do it with `m_pSplitMainWin` object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize QSplitter handle color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924036/customize-qsplitter-handle-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS syntax is wrong. It should read

```
QSplitter::handle { background-color: rgb(55, 100, 110); }
```

Comment: But its not setting the color on Handle, I need to set it through m_pSplitMainWin object

Comment: So, `m_pSplitMainWin->setStyleSheet("QSplitter::handle { background-color: rgb(55, 100, 110); }");` does not work?